# C++ usage of a (shared) variable between two threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, shared-memory

FileA.h

```
struct MyCounter{
int count;
};

class Counter {
public:
    MyCounter mycounter;
    void CreateThread(); // starts a thread
    void DestroyThread();
    void PrintCount(); // this function is called while the thread is running, 
                       // reads the value of "count" and prints and is protected by a mutex while reading
};

class Singleton {
public:
    Singleton& getInstance();
    Counter counter;
};
```

FileB.cpp

```
// create static Singleton object say, S = Singleton->GetInstance()

void func1() {
    S.counter.mycounter.count++; // My question is here: Is it okay to increment this counter here without using a mutex?
}

void func2() {
    S.counter.CreateThread(); // Create a thread here
}
```

What is the best way to increment the "count" variable which is thread safe?

Comment: Could you just make it `atomic<int>`?

Comment: It's strange for a singleton's `getInstance` to return by value. You probably meant to return `Singleton&`.

Comment: I could use atomic<int> if it was a primitive but what if it is struct? Let me edit my question. Thanks.

Comment: The rule is you need synchronization if you have more than one thread and at least one of them is a writer and the threads are accessing the same object.

Comment: If it's not primitive take care that you are not trying to protect at the wrong level. Inside `Counter` `count` could still be `atomic<int>` and you don't need to protect `Counter`.If you have to, for example, "simultaneously"  change two variables, consider using a `std::mutex`.

Comment: you mean something like this:
struct Counter
{
   atomic<int> count

Comment: Yes.  Always try to keep the protection as narrow as possible, but when you do have a complicated case take care that you don't narrow the protection too much. [Famous example of too narrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-and-stack-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated).

Comment: Can someone please point me to a good example of using a std::atomic<struct_>? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what answer you want beyond using `std::atomic` if that does what you need and a mutex if not.